# Mysql errno 1242 subquery returns for than one column

Tags: mysql, error-handling, triggers

I have created a trigger to ensure that en employees shift does not overlap with another shift of this employee but when an employee has more tha one shift on the same day i get the error "subquery returns more than one column" is there a fix for this?

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER work_time_constraints
BEFORE INSERT ON shifts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF new.start_time BETWEEN (SELECT start_time FROM shifts WHERE new.employeeID = employeeID 
AND CONVERT(new.start_time, DATE) = CONVERT(start_time, DATE)) 
AND (SELECT end_time FROM shifts WHERE new.employeeID = employeeID AND CONVERT(new.end_time, 
DATE) = CONVERT(end_time, DATE))

OR new.end_time BETWEEN (SELECT start_time FROM shifts WHERE new.employeeID = employeeID AND 
CONVERT(new.start_time, DATE) = CONVERT(start_time, DATE)) 
AND (SELECT end_time FROM shifts WHERE new.employeeID = employeeID AND CONVERT(new.end_time, 
DATE) = CONVERT(end_time, DATE))

THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MYSQL_ERRNO = 9997,
MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Shift overlaps existing shift for this employee';
END IF;
END//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Your subqueries (`(SELECT start_time FROM ..`) really may return more than one row. PS. Your logic is wrong. Imagine that the shift to be tested inclides some shift completely - your logic does not test such case as overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER work_time_constraints
BEFORE INSERT ON shifts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
            FROM shifts 
            WHERE employeeID = NEW.employeeID
              AND DATE(start_time) < DATE(NEW.end_time)
              AND DATE(NEW.start_time) < DATE(end_time) ) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MYSQL_ERRNO = 9997, MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Shift overlaps existing shift for this employee';
END IF;
END
```